# Given a number X, estimate where in an ordered list of primes that number may fall

Tags: algorithm, search, primes

Given a pre-calculated ordered list of primes, and a supplied number X, I want to estimate roughly where X would fall in the list of primes, and start searching at that point.

So, I have calculated and stored a list of primes from 1..2^32-1, in a binary file.  I've got methods in a program that runs against that file to give me the nth prime, a random prime, how many primes exist, etc.  But in order to add a function to this program to tell me where a supplied number is prime, I am having trouble coming up with a way to estimate where to begin searching.  Doing it the naïve O(n) method quickly becomes infeasible, even for numbers < 2^32.

I've tried the Prime Number Theorem's (x/ln x), and done research in some other areas, but haven't quite found the right distribution, and I'm afraid my number theory isn't up to par.

I'm looking for something like, e.g.

```
1 2 3 4  5  6 .. 100 ..  500 .. 1000 ..  5000 ..  10000
2 3 5 7 11 13 .. 541 .. 3571 .. 7919 .. 48611 .. 104729
```

So, lookup(13) would give me a number near, but <= 6, lookup(7920) would give me a number <= 1000, and lookup(104729) would give a number <= 10000, etc.

P.S. I realize this is a stupid method for several reasons: a) I could store it in a different way and have O(1) lookups; b) I could compress the storage substantially; c) for such small numbers, I could do a prime test on the given number at runtime, skip the lookup table entirely, and it would be faster.  I'm *not interested in solutions for these issues*; I *genuinely want to know if there is a proven method of estimating where in a sorted list of primes a given number may fall*.  Hence, this is more a mathematical/number-theory question than an implementation question.

P.P.S. It's not homework.

P.P.P.S. I did a pretty thorough search on StackOverflow, but may have missed a direct answer to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to know for certain whether a number is prime or not, or is "very probably prime" good enough?

Comment: Well, in the end, I'll need to know for sure.  But, with a precomputed, sorted list that I know is accurate, verifying that is as simple as checking if it's in the file.  I just wanted to know if there's a way to find a starting position to search from, rather than a straight linear search.  Got a couple of good ideas from the comments below now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of primes less than x is approximately the logarithmic integral of x, li(x).  Inverting the function* gives a very good estimate of how large the k-th prime is.

If you want to avoid programming the logarithmic integral, a reasonable approximation is

*k* ln *n* + *k* ln ln *k* - *k*

After looking at the value at that point in the table, you can estimate the correct position even more accurately by using the density of prime numbers at that point.  So if you wanted the millionth prime and estimated it to be 15,502,175 but found that the nearest prime at that point was the 1,001,000-th, you could re-estimate the millionth prime as old estimate - 1000 ln(15502175).

* Technically, the function isn't bijective and hence not invertable, but it's easy enough to invert on the region you care about, say x >= 2.

Comment: Wow, that's a really close approximation, when running it a couple of times!  Since it overshot on 1,000,000, but the second calculation puts you to within 250 of the actual value, do you know if there is any pattern as numbers get larger, to how many times the adjustment needs to be run? (not for the algorithm, as simply comparing the numbers at that point would work; just out of curiousity.)

Comment: I wouldn't run the adjustment more than once -- after that first calibration I'd just step through the list (or sieve the appropriate range, if no list was available).  In general, the behavior of the error between the actual number of primes up to some point and the logarithmic integral is complicated; if we knew how to give a reasonable bound on how much it would move around that would solve the Riemann Hypothesis (which we expect is true).

Comment: But if we assume the RH is true, the maximum amount of error between the two functions is close (polylogarithmic) to the minimum amount of oscillation that we know it must display!  So there's really not much more to say than that, at least until mathematics has a deeper understanding of the zeta function (which is responsible for the particular form the error takes).

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the updates and the information.  I really need to take a number theory course...

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Number_of_prime_numbers_below_a_given_number to the rescue.

Comment: Argh; one of those is indeed the x/ln x that I thought I had tried before, but it is turning up better results for me this time.  PEBCAK on my part.  Thank you, there are several algorithms on there that look useful.

Comment: Heh, I think I wrote that section in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstood the question but wouldn't simple binary search find the right pair in the ordered list?

Comment: A binary search would work, and since there are 203280221 primes between 1..2^32, it would take a maximum of 28 seeks in the file, which would be great.  My question was about the number theory behind prime spacing, though, not the implementation.