# reporting all prime numbers less than n

Tags: primes

I need to print all the prime numbers less than a given number n. I can use sieve of Eratothenes but the running time of that algorithm IS NOT O(n). Is there any O(n) time solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll find an algorithm for checking an *arbitrary* number for primality with an O(n) time complexity. I'm pretty certain the NSA (and any other organisations that deal with crypto issues) wouldn't be very happy with that :-)

The only way you'll get an O(n) or better way is to pre-calculate (for example) the first fifty million primes (or use [someone else's already-precalculated list](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/)) and use that as a lookup. I have such a file locally and it's a simple matter of running `grep` over it to see if the number is prime. It doesn't help for arbitrary numbers but I rarely have to use ones that big. Crypto guys, of course, would consider such a list vanishingly small for their purposes.

And, if you turn it into a bitmap (about 120M for the first fifty million primes), you can even even reduce the complexity to O(1) by simply turning the number into a byte offset and bit mask - a couple of bit shifts and/or bitwise operations.

However, getting a *list* of the primes below a certain `n` is certainly doable in O(n) time complexity. The [Atkin and Bernstein paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-246/S0025-5718-03-01501-1/S0025-5718-03-01501-1.pdf) detailing the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) claims:

> We introduce an algorithm that computes the prime numbers up to N using `O(N/log(log(N)))` additions ...

which is actually slightly *better* than O(n).

However, it's still unlikely to compete with a lookup solution. My advice would be to use Atkin or Eratosthenes to make a list - it doesn't really matter since you'll only be doing this bit *once* so performance would not be critical.

Then use the list itself for checking primality.

Comment: Depending on your hardware, and your program, sometimes Sieving can be faster than reading a list from disk.  A fast assembler implementation will beat slow disk.

Comment: I wouldn't be too certain about _that._ My `grep` for the 50 millionth prime took under half a second. The sieve took one minute and ten seconds and, though it could be argued that it now knows about _all_ primes below that number, so does the `grep` solution with a slightly more complex search term or using `grep` to get the line number and `head` to print them all out up to that point). Trial division for a specific value was much faster but that will likely slow down quite a bit once you move out of the realm of native integers and into using a bignum library.

Comment: Fast disk and slow sieve. ;) I'm not so sure whether the disk is actually fast for today, but the sieve is definitely slow. My segmented Eratosthenes-type sieve in Haskell finds the 50-millionth prime in 3.2 seconds, D.J. Bernstein's primegen finds it in 0.5 seconds. (But if I really want the n-th prime and not the first n primes, I use a faster method.)

Comment: lookup for a prime on binary file (or any with fixed width representation of ints) should be O(1), using prime estimate formulas. more here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4709871/849891 .

Comment: Note: the Atkin and Bernstein paper refers to an esoteric adaptation of the basic Sieve of Atkin which will improve the asymptotic computational complexity from O(n) to O(n / log log n) but to my knowledge there has never been an implementation of that special "lattice point" technique, including by its authors.  The usually implemented SoA is O(n), which is better than the usual O(n log log n) of the SoE.  Speed is not dependent on big O performance, as the Pritchard wheel sieve has O(n / log log n) performance and can be implemented, but has constant factor overheads that cancel the gain.

Answer (score 2):

The Sieve of Eratosthenes has time complexity O(n log log n). The function log log n grows very slowly; for example, log(log(10^9)) = 3. That means you can effectively treat the log log n part of the time complexity as a constant, and ignore it, giving a time complexity of "nearly" O(n).

There are various algorithms that operate in time O(n) or O(n / log log n), including Pritchard's wheel sieves and Atkins' sieve. But constant factors generally make those algorithms slower in practice than the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Unless you need extreme speed, and you know what you are doing, and you are willing to spend lots of time doing it, the practical answer is the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Your question says that you are going to print the list of primes. In that case, output will dominate the run time of any algorithm you choose. So do yourself a favor and implement a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes.