# Improving runtime on Euler #10

Tags: python, performance, math, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So I was attacking a Euler Problem that seemed pretty simple on a small scale, but as soon as I bump it up to the number that I'm supposed to do, the code takes forever to run. This is the question:

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

I did it in Python. I could wait a few hours for the code to run, but I'd rather find a more efficient way to go about this. Here's my code in Python:

```
x = 1;
total = 0;

while x <= 2000000:
    y = 1;
    z = 0;
    
    while x >= y:    
        if x % y == 0:
            z += 1;   
        
        y += 1;
            
    if z == 2:
        total += x
    
    x += 1;
            
print total;
```

Comment: In order to find a prime instead of looping all numbers against it just loop from 2 to the root of the number and if there are any matches - you know it's not a prime. That'd make your code run in `O(n * sqrt(n))` instead of `O(n ^ 2)`

Comment: You may also want to look into more efficient prime-generating algorithms like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), the [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin), or the [Sieve of Sundaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes would be a far better choice. It takes up `O(n)` extra space, which is an array of length ~2 million, in this case. It also runs in `O(n)`, which is astronomically faster than your implementation, which runs in `O(n²)`.

I originally wrote this in JavaScript, so bear with my python:

```
max = 2000000    # we only need to check the first 2 million numbers
numbers = []
sum = 0

for i in range(2, max):    # 0 and 1 are not primes
    numbers.append(i)      # fill our blank list
for p in range(2, max):
    if numbers[p - 2] != -1:   # if p (our array stays at 2, not 0) is not -1
        # it is prime, so add it to our sum              
        sum += numbers[p - 2]
        # now, we need to mark every multiple of p as composite, starting at 2p
        c = 2 * p
        while c < max:
            # we'll mark composite numbers as -1
            numbers[c - 2] = -1
            # increment the count to 3p, 4p, 5p, ... np
            c += p

print(sum)
```

The only confusing part here might be why I used `numbers[p - 2]`. That's because I skipped 0 and 1, meaning 2 is at index 0. In other words, everything's shifted to the side by 2 indices.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the long pole in this tent is computing the list of primes in the first place.  For an artificial situation like this you could get someone else's list (say, [this](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/) one), prase it and add up the numbers in seconds.

But that's unsporting, in my view.  In which case, try the sieve of atkin as noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715256/reporting-all-prime-numbers-less-than-n) SO answer.